# Split string with regular expression accur 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, regex, split, undefined

I expect to extract the following fields from URL like protocol, domain name, port and path.

I know this `split` function is helpful to me. This is my code

```
"https://www.test.com:8081/a/b/c".split(/(:\/\/)|(:)|(\/)/)
```

The result is

```
["https", "://", undefined, undefined, "www.test.com", undefined, ":", undefined, "8081", undefined, undefined, "/", "a", undefined, undefined, "/", "b", undefined, undefined, "/", "c"]
```

I expect the result is

```
['https', '://', 'www.test.com', ':', '8081', '/', 'a/b/c']
```

Why occur `undefined` ? How to correct my regex expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing groups get included in the result of a `split`, of course - when you alternate with a capturing group that *doesn't* match on a particular iteration, that capturing group will not have matched, but it's still a capturing group inside a `split`, so `undefined` is added to the array at that position instead. For example:

```js
console.log('abc'.split(/b|(wontmatch)/));

// a more complicated example:

console.log('abcde'.split(/(b)|(d)/));

/*
[
  "a",        split substring
  "b",        b was captured, so it's included in the match
  undefined,  the (d) part did not match, but it's another capturing group, so "undefined"
  "c",        split substring
  undefined,  the (b) part did not match, but it's another capturing group, so "undefined"
  "d",        d was captured, so it's included in the match
  "e"         split substring
]
*/
```

The behavior you're experiencing is simply an even more complicated version of the above.

You might consider using `match` instead of `split`, it'll probably be easier to understand:

```js
const str = "https://www.test.com:8081/a/b/c";
const matches = str.match(/([^:]+)(:\/\/)([^:]+)(:)(\d+)(\/)(.*$)/);
console.log(matches);

// I expect the result is
// ['https', '://', 'www.test.com', ':', '8081', '/', 'a/b/c']
```

Or, if you *only* want protocol, domain name, port and path, remove the useless capture groups:

```js
const str = "https://www.test.com:8081/a/b/c";
const [, protocol, domain, port, path] = str.match(
  /([^:]+):\/\/([^:]+):(\d+)\/(.*$)/
);
console.log(protocol, domain, port, path);
```

If the port is optional, then put it and the preceding `:` into an optional non-capturing group, and change the second character set to `[^:/]` to make sure it doesn't match slashes:

```js
const str = "https://www.test.com/a/b/c";
const [, protocol, domain, port, path] = str.match(
  /([^:]+):\/\/([^:/]+)(?::(\d+))?\/(.*$)/
);
console.log(protocol, domain, port, path);
```

Comment: The port is optional. If str is 'https://www.test.com/a/b/c', your snippet don't work.

Comment: There is still a little bug. [^:] should be [^:\/]. The correct regex expresion is /([^:]+):\/\/([^:\/]+)(?::(\d+))?\/(.*$)/

Answer (score 1):

When you put capture groups in the regexp, the result includes entries for whatever matches each group. Since your groups are in different alternatives, when one alternative matches, the others will not be used, so the corresponding elements in the result will be `undefined`.

Instead of putting a group in each alternative, wrap the group around all of them.

```js
console.log("https://www.test.com:8081/a/b/c".split(/(:\/\/|:|\/)/));
```

Comment: Thanks you for your explaination. Is it possible to split the path name as a whole, not '/','a' '/b','/c' ?

Comment: Get rid of the `\/` alternative.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a real URL parser instead of a regular expression and `split()`.

Comment: But if you take `/` out of the delimiters, it won't split after `8081`. Regular expressions are not appropriate for such complicated context-dependent parsing.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to extract the parameters using `URL` object

```js
var url = new URL('https://www.test.com:8081/a/b/c');
console.log(url.protocol);
console.log(url.hostname);
console.log(url.port);
console.log(url.pathname);
```

Comment: IE don't support URL object.

Comment: Although `URL` may help the OP and their specific use here, it does not answer the question for readers wanting to understand string split with regex.